# How do I write my css for list-syle nested upto the nth degree?

Tags: html, css, nested-lists

I have a list with multiple nesting. How do I write my css so that the 1st level gets list-style as disc, the 2nd as circle and the 3rd and square and so on...?

My html is as follows

```
<ul>
  <li>Alpha</li>
  <li>Beta
    <ul>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Mango
       <ul>
        <li> Item 1<li>
        <li> Item 2</li>
          .
          .
            .
            .
                nesting up to the nth degree
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If you're hoping for some sort of `nth-child` solution where the styles repeat (eg. 10th level list has the same styles as the first level list), this is not possible with pure CSS.  You must write a selector for each level of nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just keep going in order as you establish your `ul` `li` combinations.

**html**

```
<div class="first">
  <ul>first
     <li>Alpha</li>
     <li>Beta
        <ul>
           <li>Omega</li>
        </ul>
     </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.first ul{
  color:red;
}
.first ul li{
  color:green;
}
.first ul li li{
  color:blue;
}
```

**example link**   :  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnwKu/1/)

Comment: Thanks but is there an nth nested li combination that I can use. I do not know how many levels will eventually be there

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="list-style:____;"` to the <ul> so it would be `<ul style="list-style:____;">` manually or create a jQuery doc with a loop that goes through each <ul> and changes its `.css("list-style:____;")` are two ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* level 1 (top) */
ul > li { list-style-type: disc; }

/* level 2 */
ul > li > ul > li { list-style-type: circle; }

/* level 3 */
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li { list-style-type: square; }

/* etc... */
```

You can also write them more generically as

```
/* level 1 */
ul li { list-style-type: disc; }

/* level 2 */
ul li li { list-style-type: circle; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can really automatically make it to make different styles to repeat by a n-element factor. What you can do is style it to a reasonable depth and then make a default style for the rest, like this.

```
ul { list-style-type: disc; }
li ul { list-style-type: circle; }
li li ul { list-style-type: square; }
```

Another solution would be to make for each style a class and assuming this is generated automatically use a counter and set the style.

```
.style1 { list-style-type: disc; }
.style2 { list-style-type: circle; }
.style3 { list-style-type: square; }
```

Then in your loop initiate a depth counter and use it to set your class:

```
<ul class="style<?php echo $depth % 3; ?>">
```

This will automatically apply styles depending of the depth, so the 4th ul will have the style1, 5th style2, 6th style3, and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I went the class route, then used a modulus to determine which list style to use. Like `myVar % 3 === 1` for the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc and `myVar % 3 === 2` for the 2nd, 5th,  8th, etc and `myVar % 3 === 0` for the 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc.